# If Then Comparison not working? Different Text Type?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I'm completely lost right now on a simple if then check for php.

My current code is:

```
 while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) {
     if ($header === null) {
         $header = $row;

         $identified = false;
         echo "Columns found in CSV<br/>";

         foreach ($row as $value) {

          echo 'Values: [' . strtolower($value) . ":" . 'first name]<br/>';
          if (strtolower($value) == strval('first name') {
             echo "is equal";
          } else {
              echo "not equal";
          }
      }
}
```

Output is currently

```
Columns found in CSV
Values: [first name:first name]
not equal
```

What am I missing??? This should be an extremely simple thing to do.  I will note that the $value is being set to text being read from a CSV file.  Is it possible the actual text is being messed with some type of encoding issue?  I've also tried to do like

```
$value = utf8_encode($value);
```

But this isn't fixing the issue either.  I'm completely stumped on this issue.  I'm trying to find out why the IF statement isn't working correctly and the values isn't equal to return "is equal" as the response.

Comment: `var_dump($value, urlencode($value))` — See what that gives you.

Comment: @deceze it returned: string(29) "First Name" string(61) "%00F%00i%00r%00s%00t%00+%00N%00a%00m%00e%00%00"  but I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: That might be UTF-16 encoded, with every other byte being a NUL byte.

Comment: @deceze if its UTF-16 am I just not able to do anything with it?  I've tried echo iconv( "UTF-16", "UTF-8", $value);  also I've tried a set_local but nothing is working.. Also I'm running php7 so the issue with 5.3 and previous not reading UTF-16 shouldn't be an issue I would presume